# Como inicializo uma lista com x posições em Python?

Tags: python, lista

Quero criar na lista x posições vazias antes de encher, como faço?

Comment: Trivialmente: `[None] * 10`; também dá pra fazer algo com `range`, mas dificilmente vai ficar mais simples do que aquilo.

Answer (score 2):

Para resolver o seu problema não será necessário nada mais do que uma multiplicação...
Da mesma forma que você pode criar um `print()` do seguinte jeito:

```
print('-' * 10)
```

Resultado:
`----------`

Você pode criar uma lista utilizando a mesma técnica.

Desta forma o código seria assim:

```
lista = [None] * 50 #o valor 50 pode ser trocado por qualquer um
```

Isto ira criar uma `lista` com 50 posições todas preenchidas com o valor `None` que posteriormente poderá ser substituído por qualquer outro valor desejado.

Para ter certeza do resultado faça os seguintes testes:

```
print(len(lista)) #ira mostrar o tamanho da lista criada. No caso aqui vai aparecer 50.
print(lista) #Mostra toda a lista com os seus valores, se você contar irá ver que possui 50 elementos.
```